# Display hierarchy tree using WinForms DevExpress XtraGrid c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tree, devexpress

I have hierarchical data structure that consists of objects like:

```
Class A
{
*some properties
*list<A> SubNodes
}
```

Right now I need to display this hierarchy in some kind of visual tree.
I'm using WinForms C#/ Can you please advice me how I can disply tree like that. Standart TreeView have no DataSource property and DevExpress XtraTreeView use DataSource plain source with Id/ParentID relation. I've used XtraGrid, but I cant configure details view correctly. Could you please tell me in which way I could handle this problem?

UPD

During day duscussions was born decision that TreeList doesn't suit us. Cause we need all that stuff with autofilter row and grouppanel (where I can drag column for grouping) that provides XtraGrid. 
So if there is no solution to implement such tree using XtraGrid I should close this question.

Comment: My class have a lot of properties like Amount, StartDate, Owner and I need to display this fields like gridrow with columns. But Tree view can show only one property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`TreeList.IVirtualTreeListData`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2486) interface.
Here is example:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string property0, string property1, string property2)
    {
        Property0 = property0;
        Property1 = property1;
        Property2 = property2;

        SubNodes = new List<A>();
    }

    public string Property0 { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public List<A> SubNodes { get; private set; }
}

public class TreeDataSource : List<A>, TreeList.IVirtualTreeListData
{
    void TreeList.IVirtualTreeListData.VirtualTreeGetChildNodes(VirtualTreeGetChildNodesInfo info)
    {
        var a = info.Node as A;

        info.Children = a.SubNodes;
    }

    void TreeList.IVirtualTreeListData.VirtualTreeGetCellValue(VirtualTreeGetCellValueInfo info)
    {
        var a = info.Node as A;

        switch (info.Column.FieldName)
        {
            case "Property0":
                info.CellData = a.Property0;
                break;
            case "Property1":
                info.CellData = a.Property1;
                break;
            case "Property2":
                info.CellData = a.Property2;
                break;
        }
    }

    void TreeList.IVirtualTreeListData.VirtualTreeSetCellValue(VirtualTreeSetCellValueInfo info)
    {
        var a = info.Node as A;

        switch (info.Column.FieldName)
        {
            case "Property0":
                a.Property0 = (string)info.NewCellData;
                break;
            case "Property1":
                a.Property1 = (string)info.NewCellData;
                break;
            case "Property2":
                a.Property2 = (string)info.NewCellData;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of example:

```
var treeDataSource = new TreeDataSource();
//Add top level nodes
treeDataSource.Add(new A("Node 0, Property 0", "Node 0, Property 1", "Node 0, Property 2"));
treeDataSource.Add(new A("Node 1, Property 0", "Node 1, Property 1", "Node 1, Property 2"));
treeDataSource.Add(new A("Node 2, Property 0", "Node 2, Property 1", "Node 2, Property 2"));
//Add subnodes for first node.
treeDataSource[0].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.0, Property 0", "Node 0.0, Property 1", "Node 0.0, Property 2"));
treeDataSource[0].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.1, Property 0", "Node 0.1, Property 1", "Node 0.1, Property 2"));
treeDataSource[0].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.2, Property 0", "Node 0.2, Property 1", "Node 0.2, Property 2"));
//Add subnodes for second node.
treeDataSource[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 1.0, Property 0", "Node 1.0, Property 1", "Node 1.0, Property 2"));
treeDataSource[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 1.1, Property 0", "Node 1.1, Property 1", "Node 1.1, Property 2"));
treeDataSource[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 1.2, Property 0", "Node 1.2, Property 1", "Node 1.2, Property 2"));

var treeList = new TreeList();

treeList.Columns.AddField("Property0").Visible = true;
treeList.Columns.AddField("Property1").Visible = true;
treeList.Columns.AddField("Property2").Visible = true;

treeList.DataSource = treeDataSource;

Controls.Add(treeList);
treeList.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Result of example:
[image: Result of example]

Comment: I'va tried your solution and created in treelist columns with sources Property0,Property1,Property2. But treelist displays only top levels, when I expand first row there going blank row.

Comment: @Kostya I have updated my answer with usage of example.

Comment: Nope, just copied your code and my TreeList just displays top level rows. When I expand there three blank rows without values.

Comment: I've just copied whole your code without any modification. Usage example pasted to button click event. Just blank form with button on it.

Comment: Great example. But the name of the second class, DataSource, has confused me a little. Can be named as MyDataSource or so.

Comment: @flexo I renamed it to `TreeDataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two recommended approaches for binding business object that encapsulates a tree structure to DevExpress TreeList:

1) To adapt the object for display in the TreeList control. In this case the object must implement a `DevExpress.XtraTreeList.IVirtualTreeListData` interface. See [this article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2486), for more information.
Example: [How to: Implement a Tree Structure for a Business Object](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5561)

2) To handle specific TreeList's events and to provide data for root and child nodes.
See [this article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5560), for more information.
Example: [How to: Load Data Dynamically via Events](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5562)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use XtraGrid for hierarchy, than you can use [`IRelationList`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5495) interface.
Here is example:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string property0, string property1, string property2)
    {
        Property0 = property0;
        Property1 = property1;
        Property2 = property2;

        SubNodes = new List<A>();
    }

    public string Property0 { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public List<A> SubNodes { get; private set; }
}

public class DataSource : List<A>, IRelationList
{
    IList IRelationList.GetDetailList(int index, int relationIndex)
    {
        return this[index].SubNodes;
    }

    string IRelationList.GetRelationName(int index, int relationIndex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    bool IRelationList.IsMasterRowEmpty(int index, int relationIndex)
    {
        return this[index].SubNodes.Count == 0;
    }

    int IRelationList.RelationCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Usage of example:

```
var dataSource = new DataSource();
//Add top level nodes
dataSource.Add(new A("Node 0, Property 0", "Node 0, Property 1", "Node 0, Property 2"));
dataSource.Add(new A("Node 1, Property 0", "Node 1, Property 1", "Node 1, Property 2"));
dataSource.Add(new A("Node 2, Property 0", "Node 2, Property 1", "Node 2, Property 2"));
//Add subnodes for first node.
dataSource[0].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.0, Property 0", "Node 0.0, Property 1", "Node 0.0, Property 2"));
dataSource[0].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.1, Property 0", "Node 0.1, Property 1", "Node 0.1, Property 2"));
dataSource[0].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.2, Property 0", "Node 0.2, Property 1", "Node 0.2, Property 2"));
//Add subnodes for second node.
dataSource[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 1.0, Property 0", "Node 1.0, Property 1", "Node 1.0, Property 2"));
dataSource[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 1.1, Property 0", "Node 1.1, Property 1", "Node 1.1, Property 2"));
dataSource[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 1.2, Property 0", "Node 1.2, Property 1", "Node 1.2, Property 2"));
//Add subnodes for second node in fisrt subnode.
dataSource[0].SubNodes[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.1.0, Property 0", "Node 0.1.0, Property 1", "Node 0.1.0, Property 2"));
dataSource[0].SubNodes[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.1.1, Property 0", "Node 0.1.1, Property 1", "Node 0.1.1, Property 2"));
dataSource[0].SubNodes[1].SubNodes.Add(new A("Node 0.1.2, Property 0", "Node 0.1.2, Property 1", "Node 0.1.2, Property 2"));

var gridControl = new GridControl();

var view = new GridView(gridControl);           

gridControl.MainView = view;
gridControl.DataSource = dataSource;
gridControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

view.OptionsDetail.ShowDetailTabs = false;

Controls.Add(gridControl);
```

Result of example:
[image: Result of example]
In additional you can take a look at [«How to emulate a TreeList using the master-detail GridView»](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2290) example.